# Gekko differentiation with Coolprop

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to solve a differential problem with Gekko for the first time. I have defined the parameters with CoolProp as suggested here: [Gekko and CoolProp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832981/gekko-and-coolprop)
I would like to have a nice plot of T over time.

```
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP 
from gekko import GEKKO
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False) 
m.time = np.arange(0,100,1)
#variables
T = m.Var(value=78+273)
p = m.Var()
d = m.Var()
c = m.Var()
# build cubic spline
T_data = np.arange(77.5+273,98.5+273,1)
p_data = [CP.PropsSI('P','T',Ti,'Q',1,"Water") for Ti in T_data]
d_data = [CP.PropsSI('D','T',Ti,'Q',1,"Water") for Ti in T_data]
c_data = [CP.PropsSI('O','T',Ti,'Q',1,"Water") for Ti in T_data]

m.cspline(T,p,T_data,p_data)
m.cspline(T,d,T_data,d_data)
m.cspline(T,c,T_data,c_data)

#equations
def x(d,c,T):
    return (50 + 0.1/d*T)/(1000*c)

m.Equation( T.dt() == x(d,c,T) )

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT) 
#m.options.coldstart = 1

m.solve(disp=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(m.time, y.value)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='T',
       title='gekko test')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

however, I get an error

> Exception: @error: Equation Definition
> Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
> (80.0/v21)(80.5/v21)(81.0/v21)(81.5/v21)(82.0/v21)(82.5/v21)
> STOPPING..

The same can be solved with scipy as follows:

```
def x(t,T):
    p = CP.PropsSI('P','T',T,'Q',1,"Water")
    d = CP.PropsSI('D','T',T,'Q',1,"Water")
    c  = CP.PropsSI('O','T',T,'Q',1,"Water")[1.0]).c
    dTdt = (50 + 0.1/d*T)/(1000*c)
    return dTdt
y0 = [78+273]
sol = solve_ivp(x, (0,100), y0, method='LSODA', rtol=1e-6)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='T',
       title='scipy test')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

The infeasibilities.txt shows (I believe) that there is something wrong with the spline?

---

***** POSSIBLE INFEASBILE EQUATIONS ************

---

---

| EQ Number | Lower | Residual | Upper | Infeas. | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0000E+00 | 8.0315E+02 | 0.0000E+00 | -8.0315E+02 | p(1).n(2).cspline1.cspline: y = p_0 + p_1 (x-x_i) + p_2 (x-x_i)^2 + p_3 (x-x_i)^3 |
| Variable | Lower | Value | Upper | $Value | Name |
| 1 | -1.2346E+20 | 7.8000E+01 | 1.2346E+20 | 0.0000E+00 | p(1).n(2).v1 |
| 3 | -1.2346E+20 | 0.0000E+00 | 1.2346E+20 | 0.0000E+00 | p(1).n(2).v3 |

---

**Any idea what causes the error and how I can get the model solved successfully?**

**Additionally, how do I include CoolProp data with two variables in an efficient and successful way?** This doesn't seem to work properly:

```
T_data = np.arange(77.5+273,98.5+273,1)
D_data = np.arange(3,1004,1)
p_data=[]
for i in T_data:
    row = []
    for n in D_data:
        row.append(CP.PropsSI('P','T',i,'D',n,"Water"))
    p_data.append(row)

m.bspline(T1,D1,p1,T_data,D_data,p_data)
```

it results in en error

> Exception: @error: Bspline Config
> bspline in bspline1_info.csv needs 3 lines: kx,ky,sf
> STOPPING...

It is a test run and familiarization with Gekko for the future more complex DAE problem, which cannot be solved with scipy. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT 22.08**
Thank you, Mr. Hedengren, for the answer below! Sadly, I still get an error when I try to do the same thing with other data, such as p or h. Simplified example:

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
u1 = m.Param(value=-81e3)
D1 = m.Param(value=808)
h1 = m.Var()
D_data = np.array([807.5, 808.0, 808.5, 809.0,809.5])
u_data = np.array([-121000, -111000, -101000, -91000,-81000])
h_data = [] 
for n in D_data:
    row = []     
    for i in u_data:         
        row.append(CP.PropsSI('H','U',i,'D',n,"Nitrogen"))
    h_data.append(row) 
# Define the B-spline interpolation
m.bspline(D1, u1, h1, D_data, u_data, h_data)

# Set solver options
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 10

# Solve the optimization problem
m.solve()
```

Could someone perhaps help me understand why the solution doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infeasible solution is because `d` and `c` are initialized to a value of `0` and they appear in the denominator of the equation. Setting `d.value=1` & `c.value=1` or initializing with `m.Var(1)` resolves the problem.

[image: solution test]

```py
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP 
from gekko import GEKKO
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def x(t,T):
    p = CP.PropsSI('P','T',T,'Q',1,"Water")
    d = CP.PropsSI('D','T',T,'Q',1,"Water")
    c = CP.PropsSI('O','T',T,'Q',1,"Water")
    dTdt = (50 + (0.1/d)*T)/(1000*c)
    return dTdt
y0 = [78+273]
sol = solve_ivp(x, (0,100), y0, method='LSODA', rtol=1e-6)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='T',
       title='scipy test')
ax.grid()


m = GEKKO(remote=False) 
m.time = np.arange(0,101,1)

#variables
T = m.Var(value=78+273)
p = m.Var(1)
d = m.Var(1)
c = m.Var(1)

# build cubic spline
T_data = np.arange(77.5+273,98.5+273,1)
#T.lower=min(T_data); T.upper=max(T_data)
p_data = [CP.PropsSI('P','T',Ti,'Q',1,"Water") for Ti in T_data]
d_data = [CP.PropsSI('D','T',Ti,'Q',1,"Water") for Ti in T_data]
c_data = [CP.PropsSI('O','T',Ti,'Q',1,"Water") for Ti in T_data]

m.cspline(T,p,T_data,p_data)
m.cspline(T,d,T_data,d_data)
m.cspline(T,c,T_data,c_data)

#equations
def x(d,c,T):
    return (50 + (0.1/d)*T)/(1000*c)

m.Equation( T.dt() == x(d,c,T) )

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT) 

m.solve(disp=False)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(m.time, T.value)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)',title='gekko test')
ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('results.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

The documentation has an example of using `bspline()`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

xgrid = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
ygrid = xgrid
xg,yg = np.meshgrid(xgrid,ygrid)
z_data = xg*yg

x = m.Var(0.5,-1,1)
y = m.Var(0.5,-1,1)
z = m.Var(2)

m.bspline(x,y,z,xgrid,ygrid,z_data)

m.Minimize(z)

m.solve()
```

The `xgrid` and `ygrid` values are vectors while the `z_data` value is a matrix. In your example, the number of column characters with `D_data` exceeds the maximum. Use `D_data` as the first entry to create something with fewer column characters and more rows. The alternative is to use fewer mesh points such as `D_data = np.arange(3,1004,10)` to also improve the speed of building the b-spline.

```
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP 
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
T_data = np.arange(77.5+273,98.5+273,1)
D_data = np.arange(3,1004,1)
p_data=[]
T1,D1 = m.Array(m.Param,2,value=100)
p1 = m.Var()
for n in D_data:
    row = []
    for i in T_data:    
        row.append(CP.PropsSI('P','T',i,'D',n,"Water"))
    p_data.append(row)

m.bspline(D1,T1,p1,D_data,T_data,p_data)

m.solve()
```

This solves successfully:

```
Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        1
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Total number of variables............................:        1
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        1
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  0.0000000e+00 4.26e+04 0.00e+00   0.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
   1  0.0000000e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 -11.0 4.26e+04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1

Number of Iterations....: 1

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Constraint violation....:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Overall NLP error.......:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00


Number of objective function evaluations             = 2
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 2
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 2
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 2
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 1
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.000
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.000

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is   0.000000000000000E+000

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   5.700000000160799E-003 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Hedengren, thank you so much for your answer! Could you perhaps look at the edit above? The solution doesn't seem to work in that case

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up question. Could you create a new question and reference this one?